# Pushing data to Dojo Filteringselect (with code)

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, dojo

I'm quite new to Zend & JSON, however I have the need to learn. What I want to achieve is: having a Dojo filteringselect (with autocomplete) control which is linked to zipcodes from a database (and which keeps track of the ID, so I can store that ID as a FK in another table (later on). The structure is MVC. I do get results from the database, however I can't seem to make it shine. Nothing shows up in the filteringselect control. So basicly the structure field of my database needs to get into the filteringsselect control and keeping track of that id, because I need it later on as a FK in another table.
Please help me out!

Table:

```
<?php
class Application_Model_Place extends FS_Model_Popo {
protected $_fields = array(
    'id'            => NULL, 
    'zip'      => NULL, 
    'name'          => NULL, 
    'up'            => NULL, 
    'structure'     => NULL);

protected $_primaryKey = array('id');
 }
```

Form:

```
$place = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_FilteringSelect('Place');
$place->setLabel('Place')
    ->setAttrib('title', 'Add a place.')
    ->setAutoComplete(true)
    ->setStoreId('placeStore')
    ->setStoreType('dojox.data.QueryReadStore')
    ->setStoreParams(array('url' => '/graph/place/autocomplete'))
    ->setAttrib("searchAttr", "structure")
    ->setRequired(true);
```

Controller:

```
class Graph_PlaceController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
public function autocompleteAction() {
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $structuur = $this->_getParam("structure", "");

    $results = FS_Model_Factory::getInstance()->place->autocomplete(array('structure like ?'=> "%".$structure."%"));
    $enc_res = array();
    foreach ($results as $value) {
        array_push($enc_res,$this->_helper->convert->toArray($value));
    }
    $this->_helper->json($enc_res);
    $data = new Zend_Dojo_Data('id', $enc_res);
    $this->_helper->autoCompleteDojo($data);
  }
}
```

An example of json($enc_res) would be:

```
{"id":"235","zip":"3130","name":"Betekom","up":"BETEKOM","structure":"3130 Betekom"}, {"id":"268","zip":"3211","name":"Binkom","up":"BINKOM","structure":"3211 Binkom"},{"id":"377","zip":"3840","name":"Broekom","up":"BROEKOM","structure":"3840 Broekom"},{"id":"393","zip":"1081","name":"Brussel (Koekelberg)","up":"BRUSSEL (KOEKELBERG)","structure":"1081 BRUSSEL (KOEKELBERG)"},{"id":"421","zip":"1081","name":"Bruxelles (Koekelberg)","up":"BRUXELLES (KOEKELBERG)","structure":"1081 BRUXELLES (KOEKELBERG)"},{"id":"668","zip":"3670","name":"Ellikom","up":"ELLIKOM","structure":"3670 Ellikom"},{"id":"1236","zip":"3840","name":"Jesseren (Kolmont)","up":"JESSEREN (KOLMONT)","structure":"3840 Jesseren (Kolmont)"},{"id":"1275","zip":"3370","name":"Kerkom","up":"KERKOM","structure":"3370 Kerkom"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have several options :

- Either you have control on the structure of the json you produce on your controller, and therefore you should generate the format expected by dojox.store.QueryReadStore (which is by default the same as dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore). See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#general-structure
- Or you create a custom store that understands the structure of your json response. See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/data/QueryReadStore.html#query-translation
- Or you are using dojo >1.6, and you can use dojo.store.JsonRest with its companion dojo.data.ObjectStore as described [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data/ObjectStore.html)

Option 1 is obviously the easiest...